# Object Generation Gaps

Tags: unity-game-engine

Help me understand what the problem is in Unity3D.
I generate an infinite number of blocks in motion.
But the higher the speed of movement, the larger the gap between objects. As far as I understand, the gap will be sampled due to the frame refresh time.

How to generate objects close to each other?

```
void Update()
{
    if (startspawn)
    {
        spawn1 = Instantiate(spawner);
        spawn1.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(15, 0, 0);
        startspawn = false;
    }
    if (spawn1.transform.position.x - startcoordinateX > size)
    {
        spawn2 = Instantiate(spawner);
        spawn2.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(15, 0, 0);
        spawn1 = spawn2;
    }
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZEDJ.png)

Comment: As far as I can tell currently all your objects are spawned at world `0,0,0` and then start moving with linear velocity so of course of the velocity gets very high it might happen that the objects move very far between two frames before the next check is done and eventually the next block is spawned ....

Comment: Yes, that is right.
The gap is created by the movement of objects between frames.
The higher the speed, the larger the clearance.
How to avoid this and spawn objects without a gap?

Answer (score 0):

Use FixedUpdate instead of Update. FixedUpdate ensures the time between calls is the same. You can read more about it here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But I have already tried different options and FixedUpdate and AddForce, which is tied to the frame rate..
Nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave it here.
Managed to solve the problem by simple binding to Time.deltaTime.
Now, even at high speed, there are no gaps.

Just use.

spawn1.GetComponent().velocity = new Vector3(**speed * Time.deltaTime**, 0, 0);

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fixed update which makes the time between calls the same.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).